Using grid with seleniumrequests library for python
I want to use the seleniumrequests library:
https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/
Tests run locally without grid work correctly. Unfortunately, when I use grid, nothing happens. The test is running but no logs appear in the console. This continues until I stop the test myself.
My configuration code:
import seleniumrequests
from seleniumrequests import Chrome
grid = True
class GlobalSet:
def get_browser_driver(self):
    """
    The method returns selenium webdriver:
        if grid is set as False:
            driver for tests run from the local machine or for jenkins
        else for tests run on the selenium grid locally
    @return driver: Driver for browser
    """
    service = Service()
    options = ChromeOptions()
    if grid:
        options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        driver = seleniumrequests.Remote("http://grid_url", options=options)
        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    else:
        prefs = {
            "download.default_directory" : self.get_sample_attachment_path(False)
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        driver = Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    return driver

Thank you very much for any help
